# How to use own method on ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a problem with a task I have to do. I need to create class Company and write few methods (such as hire, fire, etc.) for Employee class objects.
Those are my classes and methods:

```
public class Company{
    ArrayList <Employee> alist= new ArrayList<Employee>();

    public void hire(Employee e) {
        int i=0;
        boolean k=false;
        while(i<alist.size()) {
            if (e.getLastName().equals(alist.get(i).getLastName())) {
                k=true;
                i++;
            }
        }
        if (k==false) alist.add(e);
        else System.out.print("Employee already exists");
    }
}

public class Employee{
    protected String lastname; //protected for subclasses
    protected double jobposition;
    public Employee(String lastname,double jobposition) {
        this.lastname=lastname;
        this.jobposition=jobposition;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastname;
}
```

And subclass which extends Employee:

```
public class OfficeWorker extends Employee {
    float pay, bonus;
    public OfficeWorker(String lastname,double jobposition,float pay,float bonus) {
        super(lastname,jobposition);
        this.pay=pay;
        this.bonus=bonus;
    }
}
```

I wanted to use `ArrayList` to do this, but it crashes in main class and I get message "The method hire(Employee) is undefined for the type ArrayList":

```
public static void main(String[]args) {

    ArrayList <Employee> list = new ArrayList <Employee>();
    Employee e1 = new OfficeWorker("Smith",0.5,2000,50);
    list.hire(e1);

}
```

Why can't I do this like that?

Comment: The `hire` method you wrote is on your `Company` class.  Why do you expect it to be on `ArrayList<>`?  What would you expect this to do?

Comment: `Company` is the the class that does the hiring. Do you mean to add the employee to the list? If so, that's done with `list.add(e1)`. I imagine what you're really going for is to create a `Company` that then hires `Employee e1`, and adds it to the `ArrayList` that's created with a `Company` instance.

Comment: Create instance of `Company` like `Company comp = new Company();` then add Employee using `comp.hire(e1);`. You already have list which stores the Employees in Company class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main method should be like:

```
public static void main(String[]args) {

    Company company = new Company();
    Employee e1 = new OfficeWorker("Smith",0.5,2000,50);
    company.hire(e1);
}
```

As you have already written method `hire()` in class `Company` which adds the `Employee` in the `ArrayList <Employee> alist`.

There is NO way you can create your own method in Java `ArrayList` class.

Comment: Seems like an obvious mistake which I didn't see, now I do, thank you very much!

Comment: @Weronika, that's an obvious mistake at initial development phase. If my answer helped solve your problem, you can accept it. Happy coding!!!

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that you are calling the method hire directly into the `ArrayList` object, instead of that, create an object called `Company`, then, once it's created, call the method of `hire` in the Company, as the `Company` already has the property of `ArrayList` in it.

```
public static void main(String[]args) {
    Company company = new Company();
    Employee e1 = new OfficeWorker("Smith",0.5,2000,50);
    company.hire(e1);
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList  list = new ArrayList ();
ArrayList  don't have hire method.
In a class you can access the method availabe in that method.And that also depends upon access modifier and where you are aceesing the method.

To access a non-static public method you have to create object and call method on that object

```
SomeClass c=new SomeClass();
c.m();
```

For static public method you can call directly

```
SomeClass.m();
```

Answer (score 0):

hire() method is defined as part of Company Class.
it should be as below.

```
Company xyz = new Company();
xyz.hire(e1);
```